# How to POST the data from a modal form of Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page using a `modal` to get the users email and I want to add it to a list of subscribers (which is a Django model). Here is the modal code for that:

```
<div id="notifications" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" ara-labelledby="Notification" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
        <h4>Subscribe to Status Notifications</h4>
    </div>
    <form>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="email" placeholder="email"/>
            <p>This service will notify you by email should any issue arise that affects your plivo service.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried to look in the Twitter Bootstrap doc but it really is minimal. I want to `POST` the data to a `Django view that's listening for`POST` requests.

This is the bare essential. I am using `regex` to compare the format of the email before storing the email id. So if the email `does not` match the `regex` the view returns an `Invalid Email`. So I would like to notify the user about that within the `modal` itself. But I really have no idea as to how to do this. Someone please help.

---

### UPDATE 1

Tried this based on karthikr's answer:

```
<form id="subscribe-email-form" action="/notifications/subscribe/" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email"/>
        <p>This service will notify you by email should any issue arise that affects your service.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <input id="subscribe-email-submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
       $('subscribe-email-form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/notifications/subscribe/",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("subscribe-email-form").serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Successfully submitted.")
                }
            });
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

There is something that is confusing me. What about the `onclick` event of the `modal button`?

I got it! I added `name="Email"` in the line `<input type="email" placeholder="email"/>`

The Django field is looking for the `Email Field`. So in my Django view the code is:

```
request.POST.get("Email", '')
```

So specifying the field name helps. But it takes me to the URL where I am posting. I want it to display a alert in the same page.

---

### UPDATE 2

So part 1 is working. As in the posts are working. Now I need to show a modal for the success or failure.

Here's what I am trying. So I created this modal with a `textarea`:

```
<div id="subscription-confirm" class="modal hide fade in" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <label id="responsestatus"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#subscribe-email-form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'notifications/subscribe/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#subscribe-email-form').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                     $('#responsestatus').val(data);
                     $('#subscription-confirm').modal('show');    
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

So the modal comes up, but the data is not `set` into the `label` field of the `modal`.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 documentation says you can have a [form within a modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content), but it does not show anything about having a modal in a form.  I wish it did!  But I guess that's why we are here.  :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to handle it via `ajax` submit.

Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#subscribe-email-form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: url, //this is the submit URL
            type: 'GET', //or POST
            data: $('#subscribe-email-form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                 alert('successfully submitted')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

A better way would be to use a django form, and then render the following snippet:

```
<form>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="email" placeholder="email"/>
        <p>This service will notify you by email should any issue arise that affects your plivo service.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

via the context - example : `{{form}}`.

Comment: you are saying I need to seperate the code into a differnt template for the form? How would I make it link with the modal then?

Comment: Well.. You can do it in a different template, but what I was saying was just make it an ajax submit. It could be in the same template

Comment: I did something similar to your answer. and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349142/twitter-bootstrap-2-modal-form-dialogs
The post is working. But the data is not passed. Can you tell why?

Comment: becaues, you are not sending the data. Try `data: $('form').serialize()` - edited the answer too

Comment: Hey I was making a mistake. I added name="Email". This is the field for which I am looking in my `django view`. But the 2nd part of question is still pending. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: i m sorry i dont understand what you mean by `But it takes me to the url where I am posting` . would be useful if you show your views too

Comment: When I submit, the page redirects to /notifications/submit BUt I want it to display an alert on the same page depending on a success or a failure.

Comment: That would never happen. Ajax submits never redirects.

Comment: But it is. Maybe not ajax submit. so I am returning a `HttpResponse` from the view. DOnt think thats the cause.

Comment: I think there needs to be some javascript for handling the return statement and accordingly setting the response message in a new modal. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes. You are.. But you need to figure out why it is redirecting firstly

Comment: I did figure out. Its because of the action and method specified in the form. So I removed it and now I see that the ajax call isnt being fired at all. what I mean is that previously the post was because of the `action` and `post` params specified in the form declaration. After removing there isnt any post at all. The url changes into this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?Email=user%2B%40example.com`

Comment: that is because of the `type: 'GET'` You are probably looking for a POST

Comment: Its working now. The second part isnt. I am updating it with what I am trying to do...

Comment: I dont get it. For GET # wont be required?

Comment: It is required. What i m saying is, Your URL change indicates that it is a GET request. What you need is `POST`

Comment: Yes I get that. I am doing a POST. But theres one last glitch. I have updated the question.

Comment: you have a syntax error - missing `'` after `show` - Also, i would just put an error message and see if it is returning the right data

Comment: Yeah it is returning the right data I am returning from my view. I need to set the data to a field in the modal. How can I do that?

Comment: Its a simple jquery replace. what is so confusing in that ?

Comment: Yeah its not working. I am trying to put the data by id. But its a modal. And its not working also.

Comment: Can you fix the form submitter so it does a catch all on the form with the button?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "catch all on the form" ?

Answer (score 8):

I was facing same issue not able to post form without ajax.
but found solution , hope it can help and someones time.

```
<form name="paymentitrform" id="paymentitrform" class="payment"
                    method="post"
                    action="abc.php">
          <input name="email" value="" placeholder="email" />
          <input type="hidden" name="planamount" id="planamount" value="0">
                                <input type="submit" onclick="form_submit() " value="Continue Payment" class="action"
                                    name="planform">

                </form>
```

You can submit post form, from bootstrap modal using below javascript/jquery code :
call the below function onclick of input submit button

```
    function form_submit() {
        document.getElementById("paymentitrform").submit();
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

You CAN include a modal within a form.  In the Bootstrap documentation it recommends the modal to be a "top level" element, but it still works within a form.

You create a form, and then the modal "save" button will be a button of type="submit" to submit the form from within the modal.

```
<form asp-action="AddUsersToRole" method="POST" class="mb-3">

    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Users/_SelectList.cshtml", Model.Users)

    <div class="modal fade" id="role-select-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="role-select-modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Select a Role</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Users to Role</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

You can post (or GET) your form data to any URL.  By default it is the serving page URL, but you can change it by setting the form `action`.  You do not have to use ajax.

[Mozilla documentation on form action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#Where_does_the_data_go)

Comment: This seems like the simplest answer. Submit a form with a modal as confirmation step. Great! The trick is excluding `data-dismiss="modal"`  from the button that triggers the form POST request.

Comment: It's great for me with form_start before modal and form_end after, many thanks !