# Posting data via a link to a bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What i'm trying to do is post a data to a bootstrap modal window, and so far without success.

I tried doing

```
<a href="#TestModal?data=testdata" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Test</a>
```

But that doesn't even open up the modal

Then i tried

```
<form action="#TestModal">
<input type="text" name="testdata" value="test" />
<input type="submit" data-toggle="modal" class="btn" value="submit" />
</form>
```

But that as well doesn't work...

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508444/how-to-post-the-data-from-a-modal-form-of-bootstrap

Comment: you can send variables to using `get/post` only to a server. modal window cant handle all these. if you tell your requirement, you can expect answer.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use parameters like this because **there isn't server
>   request** when you click on this link. It's just an anchor and it's
>   the navigator which execute this action. Use javascript/jQuery to get
>   data.